# Access the data form Coursera api using jquery jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, jsonp, coursera-api

Today I was trying to access the coursera api using jquery after reading the [Coursera catalog](https://tech.coursera.org/app-platform/catalog/) documentation. I wrote a code and got an error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` So did some google and found that Jsonp can be used to make the cross domain request. So I simply used a $.ajax function to make a request to this [url](https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses?ids=2,3&fields=language,shortDescription&includes=sessions&fields=status&categories) or say this [simple url](https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses/2) and some other such urls, but failed.

Data on the url is  like `{"elements":[{"id":2,"shortName":"ml","name":"Machine Learning","links":{}}],"linked":{}}`

I wrote the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses/2",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'localJsonpCallback',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(){
        alert("success");
    },
    error:function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){
        alert("textStatus : " + textStatus + "\n error" + error);
    }   
  }); 

  function localJsonpCallback(data) {
  alert("localJsonpCallback : " + data);
  }
  });
```

The above code fails and goes to the error handler and the error its printing is  , `textstatus: parseError` and `Error: localJsonpCallback was not called`. I am not getting whats wrong with the code. Moreover in the console I am getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`  and `2?callback=localJsonpCallback&_=1418037208234:1` when using url https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses/2.

Is it necessary to use the jsonp call back function? Can't we handle the direct response in success handler.

Comment: I have put these files on my desktop. I am basically trying to create a chrome-extension and so I have to put these files in some non-server directory.

Comment: I think Coursera API does not support JSONP :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## this works

you can handle directly in `success` callback

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses/2",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));
    }
  }); 
});
```

returned

```
 {
    "elements": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "shortName": "ml",
            "name": "Machine Learning",
            "links": {}
        }
    ],
    "linked": {}
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Its working on server side. Thanks . Have to put this code in a file which resides under `var/www/`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$.getJSON("https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses?ids=2,3&fields=language,shortDescription&includes=sessions&fields=status&categories", function (response) {
alert(JSON.stringify(response));
},'jsonp'); 
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/45634pnt/)

Comment: Its working on server side. Thanks . Have to put this code in a file which resides under `var/www`.

Answer (score 2):

In our case you don't need use jsonp, you can use usual ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses/2",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (res) {
      console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert("textStatus : " + textStatus + "\n error" + error);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/payare/1/edit?js,console